# checkpointLocation requires correct hdfs path

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark.

I try to work with streams.

I wrote the following code:

```
streaming_query = input_df.groupBy("sensor_id").count().writeStream \
                          .format("console") \
                          .outputMode("update") \
                          .option("timestampFormat", "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS") \
                          .option("checkpointLocation", os.path.join(basepath, "Spark-Streaming-Demo")) \
                          .trigger(processingTime="1 second") \
                          .start()
streaming_query.awaitTermination()
```

However, when running this piece of code I get the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file file:/path/on/local-system/state/0/0/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0,part=0),dir = file:/path/on/local-system/state/0/0]: file:/path/on/local-system/state/0/0/1.delta does not exist
```

I think `checkpointLocation` should be a HDFS filepath and not a local absolute path.

How do I find out the HDFS URI for `os.path.join(basepath, "Spark-Streaming-Demo")`?

Comment: Yes it needs to be HDFS. See https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/checkpoint-storage-structured-streaming/read

Comment: Okay, but what is the path of the file? How do I find this out?

Comment: You will have to have set that yourself.

Comment: why not print out the variable?

Comment: Yes yes, so how do you do this??

Comment: just add a print statement in scala I would assume

Comment: Print what variable?

Comment: os.path.join(basepath, "Spark-Streaming-Demo"))

Comment: aaahhh .... nooooo. I want to translate the output of this path to an HDFS path. And btw. this is Python

Comment: then provide the path explcitly

Comment: Oh really? I never thought about that! You are an intelligent and talented being... Any other smart tips and tricks?

Comment: Well quite busy but would like in config files of spark

Comment: @toom maybe there's a simpler solution, but overall HDFS APIs can also work on a local machine path. you can set "fs.defaultFS" in the sqlContext conf, to point to a local HDFS endpoint, and later set the checkpointLocation to be a path related to this local HDFS. Of course you will also have to set up this local HDFS. This goes together with real life scenarios where you use HDFS apis when running in cluster and you only need to change the config so in tests it will run on the local file system.

Comment: @toom another complex solution which I never tried is to use a custom checkpoint manager https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/custom-checkpoint-file-manager-structured-streaming/read